# How can I anchor my absolute button to the end of a div/container so that when I scroll that div/container to right it will remain in the same place

Tags: javascript, html, css, styled-components

I created a "carousel component" and this carousel has a close button named CloseButton (in the bottom container), in case that the user wants to close the carousel [![the carousel component][1]][1] .
I want that button to be anchored to a fixed position, so that when I scroll the container to the right, that button remains displayed.
The component that contain the button is BottomCarouselContainer.

```js
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

const GalleryContainer = (props) => {
    const arrayOfImages=[...props.arrayImages];
    const [selectedImage, setSelectedImage]=React.useState(arrayOfImages[0])

    const image=arrayOfImages.map(imageName =>(
        <Photo 
            key={arrayOfImages.indexOf(imageName)}
            img={require(`../../media/images/${props.folder}/${imageName}.JPG`)}
            onClick={()=>setSelectedImage(imageName)}
        />
    ))

    function goToNextImage(){
        if(arrayOfImages.indexOf(selectedImage)+1 <arrayOfImages.length)
            setSelectedImage(arrayOfImages[arrayOfImages.indexOf(selectedImage)+1]);
    }
    function goToPreviousImage(){
        if(arrayOfImages.indexOf(selectedImage)>0)
            setSelectedImage(arrayOfImages[arrayOfImages.indexOf(selectedImage)-1]);
    }
  return (
    <>  
        <PhotoGalleryContainer display={props.display}>
            <PhotoContainer  img={require(`../../media/images/${props.folder}/${selectedImage}.JPG`)}>
                <ArrowButton onClick={()=>goToPreviousImage()}>&#60;</ArrowButton>
                <RightArrow onClick={()=>goToNextImage()}>&#62;</RightArrow>
                <BottomCarouselContainer> 
                    <FixedContainer>
                        <CloseButton>X</CloseButton>
                    </FixedContainer>
                    <Background arrayOfImages={arrayOfImages}/>
                    {image}
                </BottomCarouselContainer> 
            </PhotoContainer>
        </PhotoGalleryContainer>
    </>
  )
}

export default GalleryContainer

const PhotoGalleryContainer=styled.div`
    background:rgba(0,0,0);
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    display:${(props)=> props.display};
    z-index:2;
    animation:showGallery 1s;

    @keyframes showGallery{
        0% { height:20%; }
        100% { height:100%; }
    }
`
const PhotoContainer=styled.div`
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background-image: url( ${(props)=>props.img});
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    display:flex;
    align-items:flex-end;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;

    @media(min-width:1068px){
        width:80%;
      }
`
const BottomCarouselContainer=styled.div`
    display:flex;
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid white;
    height:30%;
    width:90%;
    margin:20px auto;
    display:${(props)=>props.display};
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto; 
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;

    &::-webkit-scrollbar {
        height:8px;
    }

    &::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px grey; 
        border-radius: 10px;
      }

    &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        border-radius: 10px;
        background: #555; 
      }

    &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
        background: #333;
      } 
`
const FixedContainer=styled.div`
    position:relative;
    padding:5px 15px 5px 15px;
`

const Background=styled.div` //for blured background
    position: absolute;
    height:100%;
    width:${(props)=>100*props.arrayOfImages.length}px; //an image is 80px and it's margins are 20px
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
`
const ArrowButton=styled.div`
    position:absolute;
    color:white;
    font-size:20px;
    z-index:3;
    top:50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 18px black;
    height:25px;
    width:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
    border-radius:5px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:25px;

    &:hover{
        cursor:pointer;
        background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    }
`
const RightArrow=styled(ArrowButton)`
    right:0;
`

const Photo=styled.div`
    height:80%;
    width:80px;
    background-image: url( ${(props)=>props.img});
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    margin:auto 10px;
    opacity: 0.6;
    z-index:2;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 18px black;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    transform: translateX(-${(props)=>props.translate}px);

    &:hover{
        opacity:1;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
`

const CloseButton=styled.div` 
    color:white;
    font-size:15px;
    top:2px;
    right:5px;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:20px;
    z-index:3;
    border-radius:50%;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    position:absolute;

    &:hover{
        cursor:pointer;
        background:rgba(255,0,0,0.7);
    }
`
```

I tried to wrap the BottomCarouselContainer, so I created a FixedContainer component with a relative position, so that the absolute button to be anchored to it. But this method does not work in my case and I dont't know why.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVeQV.jpg

Comment: Why not you use position fixed?? And use position relative on the parent of the carousel items. So, in this way, it remain at the same position even if you go to the next item.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I used position fixed and then I added a new child for BottomCarouselElement, that took from him the overflow property. And then to anchor the button to the the container and not to the viewport, I added to BottomCarouselContainer the property :transform: translateX(0);

Comment: Great. Hope the issue is fixed.